# Would it be grammatically correct to user "pointers" or "a pointer" if in each tuple is only included 1 pointer to the other country?

Tags: conjunctions, singular-vs-plural

I have the sentence:

> Upon signing an alliance treaty, the "allies" tuples of both involved players will be appended with **pointers** to one another.

Question:
Would it be grammatically correct to user "pointers" or "a pointer" if in each tuple is only included 1 pointer to the other country?

Comment: They have pointers to each other, yes?  So plural is more accurate.  A is the ally of B and B is the ally of A.

Comment: ***appended with** pointers* is unclear and unidiomatic.  Are pointers being appended **to** the tuples? If so, *pointers are appended to the "allies" tuples* or *the "allies" tuples have pointers appended to them*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one allies tuple per player and two players per alliance treaty, when you update the tuples you're appending **a pointer to each of them** or **pointers to both of them**. Either is acceptable. The first is unambiguous, while the second does not explicitly specify how many pointers you are adding to each tuple. So if you want to be crystal clear about exactly what is going on, you might want to say:

> Upon signing an alliance treaty, a pointer to the other signing player will be appended to each involved player's "allies" tuple.

*Appended with pointers to one another* doesn't quite work because an addition is appended *to* something. The entity being added to is not appended *with* the addition. Also, it reads as though the pointer is to the other player's allies tuple, rather than to the other player. If that is the intended meaning, just use *the other signing player's* instead of *player*.